# bash: make array from table

Tags: arrays, bash

I am operating with the multiple column data:
ID,num,score

```
7LMQ,Y6G,1.99
7LAA,Y65,2.95
7LZZ,Y55,8.106
7LDD,YAA,9.063
7N66,0HG,6.042
7444,HOP,5.02
7LJF,HEI,5.14
7LFD,LAL,4.128
7KCV,Cho,4.31
7GHJ,Ro,9.045
```

using some simple script I need to create two bash arrays from this data:

1. a simple array containing elemements from the second column:

   sdf_lists=("Y6G" "Y65" "Y55" "YAA" "0HG" "HOP" "HEI" "LAL" "Cho" "Ro")
2. an associative array made from the elements of the 2nd and the 1st columns:

   dataset=( [Y6G]=7LMQ [Y65]=7LAA [Y55]=7LZZ [YAA]=7LDD [0HG]=7N66 [HOP]=7444 [HEI]=7LJF [LAL]=7LFD [Cho]=7KCV [Ro]=7GHj ).

Do I need something complex like AWK to achive it or simple GREP solution will work as well?

Comment: hi, is your data available in csv format ??

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead. And do not forget to explain what format you use (CSV, TSV...)

Comment: I am terrible sorry, actually I tried to paste it in csv initially... so it's been edited :-)

Comment: I would do this completely in bash, i.e. [1] read the file line by line, [2] split each line into the fields, and [3] populate the two arrays. Don't forget to think about, whether the values in the second column can occur multiple times, or are unique (like in your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash by itself is all you need

```sh
declare -a sdf_lists=()
declare -A dataset=()

while IFS=, read -r id sdf value; do
  sdf_lists+=("$sdf")
  dataset[$id]="$sdf"
done < file.csv

declare -p sdf_lists dataset
```

result

```
declare -a sdf_lists=([0]="Y6G" [1]="Y65" [2]="Y55" [3]="YAA" [4]="0HG" [5]="HOP" [6]="HEI" [7]="LAL" [8]="Cho" [9]="Ro")
declare -A dataset=([7LMQ]="Y6G" [7LJF]="HEI" [7444]="HOP" [7GHJ]="Ro" [7KCV]="Cho" [7N66]="0HG" [7LFD]="LAL" [7LZZ]="Y55" [7LDD]="YAA" [7LAA]="Y65" )
```

---

To address Andre Wildberg's appropriate concern about CSV data, with bash **5.1**, we can do

```sh
enable -f /usr/local/lib/bash/csv csv     # your location may be different

while IFS= read -r line; do
  csv -a fields "$line"
  sdf_lists+=("${fields[1]}")
  dataset[${fields[0]}]="${fields[1]}"
done < file.csv
```

Or, use a tool like python or ruby that ship with CSV modules in their standard library.

Comment: Careful: This fails on quoted commas and probably all sorts of whitespace characters.

Comment: It would have trouble with quoted commas, but not whitespace.